# Swing media player using DSMovie

Tags: java, swing

I use `DSMovie` class to play media player files in my `Swing` app.
I need help to change the volume.

```
//play movie
DSMovie movie = new DSMovie(filename,DSFiltergraph.RENDER_NATIVE,this);

//stop movie
movie.stop();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have never used DSMovie, but after ~1 minute of internet research I found this:

[setMasterVolume(float)](http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj/javadoc/de/humatic/dsj/DSMovie.html#setMasterVolume%28float%29)

So please just read the API documentation before starting to use it

Comment: i searched the internet for more then 1 minute and found the documentation of setMasterVolume(float). the problem is thet  the class i use dont have this function, i have setVolume(float) that do nothing when i use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the way:

```
DSMovie movie = new DSMovie(filename,DSFiltergraph.RENDER_NATIVE,this); 
movie.setVolume(1);

//to raise the volume
movie.setVolume(movie.getVolume()+0.02);

//to lower the volume
movie.setVolume(movie.getVolume()-0.02);
```

Thanks.